# how to change the name of the keys in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a code that the key R and P emits a sound and saves them in a list the times the keys are pressed, my question is how do I change the name of the keys each time they are pressed?

Here is a part of the code:

```
from array import array 
import pygame 
from pygame.mixer import Sound, get_init,  pre_init

class Note(pygame.mixer.Sound): 

    def __init__(self,key, frequency, volume=.1): 
        self.frequency = frequency 
        Sound.__init__(self, self.build_samples()) 
        self.set_volume(volume)
        self.key=key
    def build_samples(self): 
        period = int(round(get_init()[0] / self.frequency)) 
        samples = array("h", [0] * period) 
        amplitude = 2 ** (abs(get_init()[1]) - 1) - 1 
        for time in range(period): 
            if time < period / 2: 
                samples[time] = amplitude 
            else: 
                samples[time] = -amplitude 
        return samples
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Note({})'.format(self.key)
pre_init(44100, -16, 1, 1024)
pygame.init() 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 480], 0) 

sounds = {} 
keymap = {pygame.K_p: 880, pygame.K_r: 440} 
key_pressed=[]
while True:

    evt = pygame.event.wait() 
    if evt.type == pygame.QUIT: 
        break 
    elif evt.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
        if evt.key in keymap: 
            note = Note(keymap[evt.key]) 
            note.play(-1) 
            sounds[evt.key] = note
            key_pressed.append(note)

    elif evt.type == pygame.KEYUP: 
        if evt.key in sounds: 
            sounds.pop(evt.key).stop()
    print(key_pressed)
```

[Image of how the keys come out when pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDylg.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean instead of `<__main__.Note object at 0x00000000037B01D0>` you want to see `Note(880)` or anything similar? Then you need to give your class a `__repr__` method.

Comment: or just access the dict value instead, `print(keymap[key_pressed])`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the representation of the objects, you have to give them a `__repr__` method that returns a string.

```
import pygame

pygame.init() 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640, 480], 0)

class Note:

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Note({})'.format(self.key)

sounds = {} 
keymap = {pygame.K_p: 880, pygame.K_r: 440} 
key_pressed = []

while True:
    evt = pygame.event.wait() 
    if evt.type == pygame.QUIT: 
        break 
    elif evt.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
        if evt.key in keymap: 
            note = Note(keymap[evt.key])
            print(note)
            sounds[evt.key] = note
            key_pressed.append(note)
        print(key_pressed)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Hi skrx. I hope you're having a good night. Edit the question with all the code and with its modifications, and to execute it, I get this error: TypeError: __init __ () missing 1 required positional argument: 'frequency'

Comment: Just remove the `key` parameter and `self.key` attribute and use the `frequency` instead. I only used the name `key` in my example because I didn't know how your class actually looked.